# How to pass list for testing in python?

Tags: python-2.7, post, testing, tastypie

I have created two dictionary in python

```
self.post_data={      
'name' : 'Org 1',
'url' : 'http://www.org1.com',
'summary' : 'This is an example org1'
}
```

second

```
self.post_data1={
'name' : 'Org 2',
'url' : 'http://www.org2.com',
'summary' : 'This is an example org2'
}
```

Now my `test_post_list` function is

```
def test_post_list(self):
    self.create_session()
    self.assertEqual(Org.objects.count(), 0)
    self.assertHttpCreated(self.api_client.post('/members/api/v1/org/', format='json', data=[{self.post_data},{self.post_data1}]))
    self.assertEqual(Org.objects.count(), 1)
```

if I pass data like this to test case, it raises an error

```
>ERROR: test_post_list (members.tests.test_org_resource.OrgTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sanky\amber\members\tests\test_org_resource.py", line 51, in te
st_post_list

    self.assertHttpCreated(self.api_client.post('/members/api/v1/org/', format='json', data={self.post_data,self.post_data1}))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`
```

How I will be able to pass list as data to `test` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this

```
data=[self.post_data,self.post_data1]
```

instead of this --

```
data=[{self.post_data},{self.post_data1}]
```

i.e no need to include dictionary inside `{}`